# How do I change my Gamertag in games?

Tags: google-plus, google-play-games

I need some help or clarification on if I can change my Gamertag in the few games that I play on my Android Device.  For example, my First Name last Initial shows up along with my Picture in all the games when I log in.  However, I would like it to show the picture but have a gamertag or use a different name other then my own.

Real Racing 3 is a prime example.  There are a ton of users using Gamertags/Avatars, however, you can only login using Facebook, some chinese website and Google +.  There is no where in there to change your name.  I have looked everywhere.

Also if you look at your trophies I would like it to show my NEW USERNAME.
Does anyone have an answer or suggestion?

Can I create a second Google+ account and not lose all the points I have acquired?  I have searched everywhere for months actually as the answers to most questions are usually found with a simple search.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your name for Google Play Games and it's related leaderboards you will have to change your [Google+ name](https://plus.google.com/me/about). There is no way to transfer your Google Play history and points to a different Google account.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!  I thought you may say that...  Kinda bummed...  So my next question would be shoud I erase all of the people connected to that Google+ Account and create another one with my real name?

Comment: That's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

**For all games:**

You can either change your Facebook or Google+ name based on the login for the specific game you play. Some games allow you to have a custom name(For ex. Bike Race). Most of the games in Play Store use Google+ signin SDK to get your profile info which includes the Profile name and Avatar. To [change your Google plus name](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1228271),

> 1. Open the Google+ app > touch the menu icon in the upper left corner.
> 2. Touch your name at the top of the screen.
> 3. Touch the gear icon in the upper right corner > Edit name.
> 4. Enter your preferred name > touch Save in the upper right corner.

You can logout and login with the same google plus account to see the updated name.

**For Real Racing 3 game:**

- Backup the app data/game progress using the cloud save option under the Settings menu found at the bottom-left corner of the Real racing Home screen.
- Click the "Backup to Cloud" and once your data is saved to cloud it will show "Last Uploaded seconds ago message".
- Sign out of the previous account and in Settings> Cloud Save > Restore to Device. This will restore the game data back to your device from the cloud.
- Now that you have all your game data, you can login with an new Facebook or Google plus id with the desired name of yours already set so that the current game progress will also be saved to your new account.

Answer (score 0):

To change your **Google play games username** follow the steps below -

- Open Google play store and search for "google play games".
- It should be already installed so you have to just open it.
- Now click on your avatar and you will see a pencil icon at the top right corner.
- Now you can edit your **Google play games username** by clicking that pencil icon.

Following the above steps will change your username across all of your games. But it **will not** change your **Google Plus profile name** (the social network).